# Pandoc problem with graph in conversion tex to docx

Tags: r, latex, knitr, stata, pandoc

I am having problem in conversion from .tex file to .docx file using pandoc. I used textdoc with stata to get the tex file. Tabularx tables dont display in the docx file, but my biggest problem is with graph that dont display in final document (docx). Lamentably the person that receive the final document need a docx. file

I am using pandoc for windows and runing from cmd windows.

```
pandoc -s tesis.tex -o output.docx
```

I tried with others indirect type of conversion:

```
pandoc -s tesis.tex -o output2.html
pandoc -s output2.html -o output6.docx
```

In other way I am able to use knitr with R to make a .tex file, but I dont if its possible to get a docx file with this method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help to see the following a complete minimal example (including some data) of what you are doing, along with a more detailed description of the problems with the output. [See the tag wiki for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing more information, as suggested in my comment and the wiki for the `stata` tag will allow folks to provide better answers. However, since your problem seems to be with the treatment of the graph in particular you can start by:

1. Checking how `texdoc` is handling the graph. [The default appears to be `.pdf`](http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/texdoc/graphs.html)
2. Make sure any `\includegraphics` Or similar references in `thesis.tex` include the `.pdf` extension. [See this discussion for more information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/how-to-convert-a-scientific-manuscript-from-latex-to-word-using-pandoc)

Comment: Thanks Arthur, sorry for my lack of information.I was complicated in adding texdoc command to my example.